# Find Type of a class implementing a generic interface

Tags: java, spring

I have a generic interface:

```
public interface Validator<T, M extends Serializable> {
...
}
```

And several classes implementing that interface:

```
public class DocumentValidator implements Validator<DocumentDto, Serializable> {
...
}

public class ContractValidator implements Validator<ContractDto, Serializable> {
...
}

public class AccountValidator implements Validator<AccountDto, Serializable> {
...
}
```

How can I programmatically find out the parameter `T`? For example, here I'm trying to filter out a specific validator out of a list of validators by passing the `T` class.

```
class SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    List<Validator> validators;
    
    public Validator getValidatorForObject(Object object) {
        validators.stream()
        .filter(v -> ???)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new 
            GenericRuntimeException(ERROR_TYPE_VALIDATOR_NOT_FOUND.getText(object.getClass()));
    }

}
```

Comment: `v.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()...`

Comment: @AndyTurner it returns Object class

Comment: That's because of your raw-typed list: `List<Validator>` should be `List<Validator<?, ?>>`.

Comment: You might want to use a `Map<Class?>, List<Validator<?, ?>>` to store your validators. Then querying becomes `validators = map.get(object.getClass())`.

Comment: `stram`? and a raw type `Validator`? but even if you correct those, what is `filter` supposed to _filter_ for, _exactly_?

Comment: @Eugene I thought it was quiet clear from the name of the method but anyway I've added more context. And sorry for the typo.

Comment: @andy it didn’t make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `T` type by java reflection, first, get the `getGenericInterfaces` then get `getActualTypeArguments`

```java
    validators.stream().filter((v) -> {
        for (Type t : v.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()) {
            ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) t;
            Type type = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            System.out.println(type);
        }
        // continue your code
        // should return boolean value
    }).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new GenericRuntimeException(ERROR_TYPE_VALIDATOR_NOT_FOUND.getText(object.getClass())));
```

, **output**

```java
class com.example.DocumentDto
class com.example.ContractDto
```